# Is there any way to find main domain with addon domain?

Tags: cdn, add-on-domain

I want to rent a host that support 8 addon domains.
I will use the Cloudflare CDN for my domains.
Please tell me is that possible for others (people or robots) to identify my other websites?
Thanks

Comment: Why does it matter if anybody can find all your websites or not? It is usually possible even if they're hosted in separate places, because your websites share commonalities such as analytics 
ids or advertising accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's important for me that no one can find my websites. If I don't use any google services on them. then nobody can find them?

Comment: It doesn't have to be Google services that link your accounts.  Any third-party JavaScript that uses an ID would introduce a problem.   Other things can fingerprint your sites too:  using the same software, using the same themes, any links between your sites, and even your writing style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just assuming you are using cPanel or some similar panel that shared hosts use.

Normally there would be no way for someone to get a list of the other domains you have setup as "Addon Domains", that being said there are a couple fringe cases to consider which differ depending on the host setup.

---

**IP Address**

Whether you have a Shared IP address which is shared amund other hosting clients or a dedicated IP address which you are using for only 1 site or using it as a shared IP for only your multiple sites you should see what happens when you attempt to load that IP directly in your browser.

While this won't just give a list of your addon domains; depending on the setup the site might redirect to, or load one of your other websites. If your using cPanel it will most likely just show a cPanel error page instead of redirecting to one of your other sites.

**Cloudflare**
Using cloudflare would solve the above issue as end users would not be able to see your hosted IP directly unless it is being leaked somewhere.

---

**Common Content**

Just like what @Stephen Ostermiller said in the comments if you are using some sort of analytics, advertising, or other thirdparty tracking codes which contain a unique ID number for your account with that platform then an end user or robot could see that multiple sites are operating with the same Analytics, Adsense, etc ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
you said: "I am just assuming you are using cPanel or some similar panel that shared hosts use" My hosting uses direct admin as control panel. is this ok?

Comment: @Sadegh Directadmin is perfectly fine, I actually perfer it over cPanel ever since the cPanel price increase. I just assumed since most of the shared hosting panels refer to it as "Addon Domains".